# htaccess ReWriteCond in reverse lookup *.abc123.com format

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using ReWrite Rules to control access to the site, when using an ip address my structure works fine.. however there is a particular provider who uses many different ip ranges which all reverse to their same domain "abc123.com", how would I express all of their ranges such as: *.abc123.com in my rewrite?  the following is what i'm using for ip's:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^123\.456\.789\.012
RewriteRule ^ - [R=403,L]
```

and i'd like to do something like:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^*.abc123.com
RewriteRule ^ - [R=403,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how would I express all of their ranges such as: *.abc123.com in my
>   rewrite?

You can use a couple of ways and try to do this. This will use referrer and if it doesn't match your host you it will deny access.

```
RewriteCond expr "! %{HTTP_REFERER} -strmatch '*://%{HTTP_HOST}/*'"
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

or you can use remote host.

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} \.abc123\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have DNS lookups turned on in your Apache/VirtualHost config using this directive:

```
HostnameLookups On
```

then you can use `REMOTE_HOST` variable for remote host name as:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} \.abc123\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Comment: I guess I need to type faster.

Comment: Aha similar answers :) but you have an additional `HTTP_REFERER` based option as well

Comment: lol, both excellent approaches. Thank you anubhava & panama Jack...  I tested the Remote Host option and it works beautifully.  wish Stacks would allow me to select both answers as you both are correct, but since it's only one and Panama needs it a little more than anubhava, I'll accept that one..  But thank you very much to both of you!